# la4j dominant eigenvalue - converting imperative algorithm to functional style in java 8

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I am working on Matrix eigenvalue problem on estimating dominant eigenvalue using the power method where A is a n x n real matrix. I'm using la4j linear algebra library. The algorithm uses below steps

1. Normalize x0 to construct a unit vector x1=x0/euclidean norm(x0)

For k=1 to kmax

2. Find x[k+1]=A[x[k]]
3. Calculate alpha[k+1]=transpose(x[k])*x[k+1]
4. Normalize x[k+1] and do not rename x[k+1]=x[k+1]/euclidean norm(x[k+1])
5. Terminating condition: if |alpha[k+1]-alpha[k]| < tolerance , stop
   Otherwise, increment k to k+1 and go to step 2

Here is my class. I would like to convert dominantEigenV to functional style using java 8. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import org.la4j.Matrix;
import org.la4j.Vector;
import org.la4j.Vectors;

public class EigenDecomp
{

public class EigenVO
{
    private double e_val;
    private Vector e_vec;

    public EigenVO(double e_val, Vector e_vec)
    {
        this.e_val=e_val;
        this.e_vec=e_vec;
    }

    public double getE_val()
    {
        return e_val;
    }

    public void setE_val(double e_val)
    {
        this.e_val = e_val;
    }

    public Vector getE_vec()
    {
        return e_vec;
    }

    public void setE_vec(Vector e_vec)
    {
        this.e_vec = e_vec;
    }
}

private Matrix A;
private Vector x0;
private double tolerance;
private double alpha0;
private int kMax;
private EigenVO result;

public EigenVO getResult()
{
    return result;
}

public EigenDecomp(Matrix A, Vector x0, double tolerance, int kMax)
{
    this.A = A;
    this.x0 = x0;
    this.tolerance = tolerance;
    this.kMax = kMax;
    this.result = new EigenVO(0.0, x0);
    this.alpha0 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

public void dominantEigenV()
{
    for (int k=1; k<kMax; k++)
    {
        alpha0=result.getE_val();
        x0=result.getE_vec();
        result.setE_vec(A.multiply(result.getE_vec().toColumnMatrix()).getColumn(0));
        result.setE_val(((Vector)x0.toRowMatrix().multiply(result.getE_vec())).get(0));
        result.setE_vec(result.getE_vec().transform(Vectors.asDivFunction(result.getE_vec().euclideanNorm())));
        System.out.println("k:"+k + ",xk:" + this.x0 + ",xkp1:" + this.result.getE_vec() + ",alpha_k:"  + this.alpha0 + ",alphak_1:" + this.result.getE_val());
        if (Math.abs(result.getE_val() - alpha0) < tolerance)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Matrix A = Matrix
    .from2DArray(new double[][] 
    { 
        { -3.0,  -4.0, -4.0 },
        {  6.0,   9.0,  6.0 },
        { -9.0, -14.0, -8.0 }
    });
    Vector x0=Vector.fromArray(new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 });
    double tolerance=0.0001;
    int kMax=50;
    EigenDecomp test=new EigenDecomp(A,x0, tolerance,kMax);
    test.dominantEigenV();
    System.out.println("eVal:" + test.getResult().getE_val());
    System.out.println("eVector:\n" + 
    test.getResult().getE_vec().toColumnMatrix().toString());
}
}
```

Below is the output of main method using a 3x3 A matrix

```
k:1,xk:0.000 1.000 1.000,xkp1:-0.288 0.540 -0.791,alpha_k:0.0,alphak_1:-7.0 
k:2,xk:-0.288 0.540 -0.791,xkp1:0.662 -0.573 0.484,alpha_k:-7.0,alphak_1:-2.49288486416559
k:3,xk:0.662 -0.573 0.484,xkp1:-0.547 0.577  -0.607,alpha_k:-2.49288486416559,alphak_1:-2.936497651061076
k:4,xk:-0.547 0.577 -0.607,xkp1:0.587 -0.577  0.567,alpha_k:-2.936497651061076,alphak_1:-2.992843189162536
k:5,xk:0.587 -0.577 0.567,xkp1:-0.574 0.577  -0.581,alpha_k:-2.992843189162536,alphak_1:-2.9992035320913533
k:6,xk:-0.574 0.577 -0.581,xkp1:0.578 -0.577  0.576,alpha_k:-2.9992035320913533,alphak_1:-2.999911487899692
k:7,xk:0.578 -0.577 0.576,xkp1:-0.577 0.577  -0.578,alpha_k:-2.999911487899692,alphak_1:-2.999990165128744
eVal:-2.999990165128744
eVector:
-0.577
0.577
-0.578
```

Comment: For the person who downvoted my question, please provide an argument. I think imperative programming style is not the way going forward and I'm looking to learn how to code in java 8 using pure functional style whenever possible.

Comment: Hi, You may take a look to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially, you should provide some research effort and/or some code to probe you already tried to solve your problem by yourself.

Comment: What is you question ? What is you problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me put your imperative method again so we can compare the two

```
public void dominantEigenV()
{
  for (int k=1; k<kMax; k++)
  {
    alpha0=result.getE_val();
    x0=result.getE_vec();
    result.setE_vec(A.multiply(result.getE_vec().toColumnMatrix()).getColumn(0));
    result.setE_val(((Vector)x0.toRowMatrix().multiply(result.getE_vec())).get(0));
    result.setE_vec(result.getE_vec().transform(Vectors.asDivFunction(result.getE_vec().euclideanNorm())));
    System.out.println("k:"+k + ",xk:" + this.x0 + ",xkp1:" + this.result.getE_vec() + ",alpha_k:"  + this.alpha0 + ",alphak_1:" + this.result.getE_val());
    if (Math.abs(result.getE_val() - alpha0) < tolerance)
    {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, all you need is to create a Consumer method and add an auxiliary method to print the values in each iteration

```
public Consumer<EigenDecomp> dominantEigenV = 
  ei->IntStream.range(1, kMax)
  .peek(k->
    ((Consumer<EigenDecomp>)e->ei.alpha0=ei.result.getE_val())
      .andThen(e->x0=ei.result.getE_vec())
      .andThen(e->ei.result.setE_vec(A.multiply(ei.result.getE_vec().toColumnMatrix()).getColumn(0)))
      .andThen(e->ei.result.setE_val(((Vector)ei.x0.toRowMatrix().multiply(ei.result.getE_vec())).get(0)))
      .andThen(e->ei.result.setE_vec(ei.result.getE_vec().transform(Vectors.asDivFunction(ei.result.getE_vec().euclideanNorm()))))
      .andThen(e->System.out.println(e.toString(k)))
      .accept(ei)
     ).allMatch(k->Math.abs(ei.result.getE_val()-ei.alpha0) > ei.tolerance);

public String toString(int k)
{
    return "k:"+k + ",xk:" + this.x0 + ",xkp1:" + this.result.getE_vec() + ",alpha_k:"  + this.alpha0 + ",alphak_1:" + this.result.getE_val();
}
```

Let me explain main parts:

```
for (int k=1; k<kMax; k++)
```

is replaced with

```
IntStream.range(1, kMax)
```

Use the peek operation to perform a consumer block after each iteration of k

```
.peek(k->
)
```

For each operation, use a chain of consumers, for enabling this inside the peek you can cast first assignment in a Consumer, followed by another assignment expressed as a lambda on second andThen() .. and so on until all assignments are performed

```
(Consumer<EigenDecomp>)e->ei.alpha0=ei.result.getE_val()).andThen(
```

After chain ends, pass accept the parameter passed ei

```
.accept(ei)
```

For stopping condition use allMatch and add a Predicate so algorithm can stop before k reaches kMax when condition is met

```
.allMatch(k->Math.abs(ei.result.getE_val()-ei.alpha0) > ei.tolerance)
```